# Rational Test Workbench iPhone - could not merge original binaries could not merge instrumented binaries

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, instrumentation, rtw, rational-test-workbench

Below given are environment specification of my system

```
System: MacBook Pro
OS X version: 10.8.5
Worklight: 6.1
Emulator: 6.1
Build for iOS: 6.1

I have installed Mobile Test Workbench 8.5.1.2 in eclipse-kepler
```

I followed instruction on the page at URL:

https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rtwhelp/v8r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.test.lt.moeb.doc%2Ftopics%2Frvar_select_device.html

but when I try to instrument and install iPhone app for simulator some error occurs every time.

Here I have copied error log from terminal which says:

```
Could not merge original binaries
Could not merge instrumented binaries
```

---

```
      ------ Start Localization Folder Creation
----- Found Localization files in: /Users/sarfaraz/Documents/workspace/SumApp/apps/SumApp/iphone/package/SumApp-1.0-iphone/Resources/Localizations.bundle/
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleDevelopmentRegion", Does Not Exist
------ Localization Folder created
51235 blocks
51235 blocks
Print: Entry, ":RMOTUID", Does Not Exist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIconFile", Does Not Exist
Print: Entry, "objects:C01FCF4F08A954540054247B:buildSettings:VALID_ARCHS", Does Not Exist
Set: Entry, "objects:C01FCF4F08A954540054247B:buildSettings:VALID_ARCHS", Does Not Exist
Print: Entry, "objects:4247AFA21330EB1200D997AA:buildSettings:VALID_ARCHS", Does Not Exist
Set: Entry, "objects:4247AFA21330EB1200D997AA:buildSettings:VALID_ARCHS", Does Not Exist
Print: Entry, "objects:1D6058940D05DD3E006BFB54:buildSettings:VALID_ARCHS", Does Not Exist
Set: Entry, "objects:1D6058940D05DD3E006BFB54:buildSettings:VALID_ARCHS", Does Not Exist
Print: Entry, "objects:1D6058950D05DD3E006BFB54:buildSettings:VALID_ARCHS", Does Not Exist
Set: Entry, "objects:1D6058950D05DD3E006BFB54:buildSettings:VALID_ARCHS", Does Not Exist
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
mergin simulator and device binaries 
lipo: can't open input file: /tmp/16329/work/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SumApp.app/SumApp (No such file or directory)
 ---- done 
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
Print: Entry, ":objects:C01FCF4F08A954540054247B:buildSettings:OTHER_LDFLAGS:0", Does Not Exist
-ObjC
Print: Entry, ":objects:C01FCF4F08A954540054247B:buildSettings:LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS:0", Does Not Exist
Print: Entry, ":objects:C01FCF4F08A954540054247B:buildSettings:LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS", Does Not Exist
-all_load
Print: Entry, ":objects:4247AFA11330EB1200D997AA:buildSettings:LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS:0", Does Not Exist
Print: Entry, ":objects:4247AFA11330EB1200D997AA:buildSettings:LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS", Does Not Exist
Print: Entry, ":objects:4247AFA21330EB1200D997AA:buildSettings:OTHER_LDFLAGS:0", Does Not Exist
Print: Entry, ":objects:4247AFA21330EB1200D997AA:buildSettings:OTHER_LDFLAGS", Does Not Exist
$(inherited)
-all_load
Print: Entry, ":objects:C01FCF5008A954540054247B:buildSettings:LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS:0", Does Not Exist
Print: Entry, ":objects:C01FCF5008A954540054247B:buildSettings:LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS", Does Not Exist
Print: Entry, ":objects:1D6058940D05DD3E006BFB54:buildSettings:OTHER_LDFLAGS:0", Does Not Exist
Print: Entry, ":objects:1D6058940D05DD3E006BFB54:buildSettings:OTHER_LDFLAGS", Does Not Exist
$(inherited)
Print: Entry, ":objects:1D6058950D05DD3E006BFB54:buildSettings:OTHER_LDFLAGS:0", Does Not Exist
Print: Entry, ":objects:1D6058950D05DD3E006BFB54:buildSettings:OTHER_LDFLAGS", Does Not Exist
$(inherited)
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
mergin simulator and device binaries 
lipo: can't open input file: /tmp/16329/work/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SumApp.app/SumApp (No such file or directory)
   ----- done
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
cp: Icon-29: No such file or directory
  adding: description.json (deflated 17%)
  adding: instrumented/ (stored 0%)
  adding: instrumented/iOS Device/ (stored 0%)
  adding: instrumented/iOS Simulator/ (stored 0%)
  adding: localize/ (stored 0%)
  adding: localize/de.lproj/ (stored 0%)
  adding: localize/de.lproj/messages.strings (deflated 62%)
  adding: localize/en.lproj/ (stored 0%)
  adding: localize/en.lproj/messages.strings (deflated 66%)
  adding: localize/es.lproj/ (stored 0%)
  adding: localize/es.lproj/messages.strings (deflated 64%)
  adding: localize/fr.lproj/ (stored 0%)
  adding: localize/fr.lproj/messages.strings (deflated 63%)
  adding: localize/it.lproj/ (stored 0%)
  adding: localize/it.lproj/messages.strings (deflated 64%)
  adding: localize/ja.lproj/ (stored 0%)
  adding: localize/ja.lproj/messages.strings (deflated 55%)
  adding: localize/ko.lproj/ (stored 0%)
  adding: localize/ko.lproj/messages.strings (deflated 55%)
  adding: localize/locales (deflated 5%)
  adding: localize/pt_BR.lproj/ (stored 0%)
  adding: localize/pt_BR.lproj/messages.strings (deflated 63%)
  adding: localize/ru.lproj/ (stored 0%)
  adding: localize/ru.lproj/messages.strings (deflated 59%)
  adding: localize/zh-Hans.lproj/ (stored 0%)
  adding: localize/zh-Hans.lproj/messages.strings (deflated 56%)
  adding: localize/zh-Hant.lproj/ (stored 0%)
  adding: localize/zh-Hant.lproj/messages.strings (deflated 56%)
  adding: original/ (stored 0%)
  adding: original/iOS Device/ (stored 0%)
  adding: original/iOS Simulator/ (stored 0%)
expr 0 * 0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12469  100   228  100 12241    439  23603 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 23585
ls: /Users/sarfaraz/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications//*/SumApp.app: No such file or directory
cp: /tmp/16329/work/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SumApp.app: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/sarfaraz/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications//*/SumApp.app: No such file or directory
cp: /tmp/16329/work/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SumApp.app: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/sarfaraz/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications//*/SumApp.app: No such file or directory
cp: /tmp/16329/work/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SumApp.app: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/sarfaraz/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0-64/Applications//*/SumApp.app: No such file or directory
cp: /tmp/16329/work/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SumApp.app: No such file or directory
"uid":"b7fd1a3aca7fd008ca5f36fe09879c1d"
Mar 21 18:15:12 2014 /Users/sarfaraz/Downloads/RTW-iOS-Build-Archive/runtime/Debug/libiOSRuntime.a
could not merge original binaries
could not merge instrumented binaries
```

Help me out here.

Comment: Please be precise: are you talking about Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight (which is from Hybrid Worklight apps) or are you talking about Rational Test Workbench, which is for fully native apps? Not the same thing.

Comment: I have installed [Mobile Test Workbench](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-mobile-test-workbench-8512-worklight#.UysdvvmSxVI)

Comment: Mobile Test Workbench 8.5.1.2 also requires the latest version of IBM Worklight 6.1.0.1. Did you upgrade Worklight before installing IMTWW 8.5.1.2?

Comment: Yes I did upgrade both the MTW and worklight,
Now I have installed fresh copy of worklight and got some new errors and the result is: Instrumented app not getting installed in the simulator. I have updated my question with new error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  executed some `terminal commands` one by one and then tried instrumentation after every execution.
Which I have listed below.

`Sudo su` only then tried = failed

`Sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app` then tried = failed

Then came out of `sudo` and tried `instrumentation` and bingo! `It succeeded!`.

```
I think Sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app worked for me.
```

Instrumentation of app in simulator succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

These errors should be a consequence of one before. Have a look on the beginning of the log file please. Check if the Apple license is OK. That usually is one of the reasons of what you have here.
Dominique

Comment: I can see that something is going wrong during instrumentation of the app but, Being new to apple and iOS things I really don't know which thing is drawing toward merge failure. 

How to check apple license?

Please draw my attention to the things which are causing failure and how I can tackle them?