# Connecting Actual iPhone to the Mobile test workbench shows white screen on iPhone

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I have installed Mobile Test Workbench 8.5.1.2 (Latest from eclipse marketplace) in Eclipse Kepler.

I have recently updated IBM Rational Test Workbench Mobile Client on iPhone.
[My previous question regarding instrumentation of iOS app for emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535140/rational-test-workbench-iphone-could-not-merge-original-binaries-could-not-mer/22634521#22634521)

Now I am trying to connect actual iPhone to the MTWW server but the application I downloaded from iTunes is not connecting to it. It only shows white screen when I hit url :

```
http://ipaddress:7878/mobile/
```

but it shows some list of URLs, including /mobile, when I hit:

```
http://ipaddress:7878/
```

The iPhone model is: 4s
iOS is: 6.1

So what can be the problem here? Whether is it bug in iOS client app?

When I try to connect it to the MTWW server running on windows machine then sometimes it gets connected.

Below given are environment specification of my system

```
System: MacBook Pro
OS X version: 10.8.5
Worklight: 6.1
Emulator: 6.1
Build for iOS: 6.1
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the Getting Started module? http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/11_08_Testing_Worklight_mobile_applications_with_the_Mobile_Test_Workbench.pdf   I was able to install the latest Worklight 6.1.0.1  and MTW 8.5.1.2 from eclipse marketplace, then from my iphone 4s (ios 6.1) hit the url listed in the Mobile Devices icon in the eclipse workbench and the mobile client displayed on my device.

Comment: Yes I did follow the Getting Started module. But for all these it is compulsory for iPhone device to get connected with MTW server and that is where I am stuck with only white screen. See `http://ipaddress:7878/` shows something but `http://ipaddress:7878/mobile` renders blank white screen.

Comment: Please see my previous commment. I was able to get this working, so I do not think this is a defect. It may be something in your environment.

Comment: fyi... I am on eclipse Kepler SR1 (4.3.1) "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers", I upgraded to Worklight 6.1.0.1 and MTWW 8.5.1.2 from eclipse marketplace, following the Getting Started module steps. I changed to the Test Workbench perspective. Opened the icon for the Mobile Devices view. Then from my iphone 4s device, pointed to the url and it brought up the mobile client on my device. If I remove the /mobile as you tried, I get a 404 not found error. You may want to try a clean environment and walk through the Getting Started module step by step.

Comment: @Barbara : I have installed IBM Rational Test Workbench Client from app-store so I think it is Web Client. When in emulator I installed it using shell script may be that can be the reason because when I try to do same thing in emulator from its browser then it also shows blank white screen. Will I have to install the same client on device too? if yes then how I can achieve same? Both the clients(iPhone: from app-store vs emulator: using shell script) looks different.

Comment: @Barbara : I tried clean environment but it didn't help.

Comment: Could it be that you have pop up windows blocked? When using the mobile test client on an iOSdevice, make sure to enable pop-up windows. Pop-up windows must be allowed for the Workbench IP address. Safari silently disables pop-up windows, and Google Chrome prompts you to allow pop up windows. See chart 17 of the "Testing IBM Worklight mobile applications with the Mobile Test Workbench" Getting Started module.